# QTableView clearSelection fails with ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h, line 282

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qt-signals

I have this class:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT
public:
...
public slot:
void select( const QItemSelection& selected, const QItemSelection& deselected);
private:
QTableView* view;
MyModelClass* model;
}
```

In my cunstructor:

```
view->setEditTriggers( QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers );
view->setSelectionMode( QAbstractItemView::SelectionMode::SingleSelection );
view->setSelectionBehavior( QAbstractItemView::SelectionBehavior::SelectRows );
connect( view->selectionModel( ), SIGNAL( selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection& ) ), this, SLOT( select( const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection& ) ) );
// and few other things
```

In my slot implementation:

```
void MyWidget::select( const QItemSelection& selected, const QItemSelection& deselected ) {
//... doing few things
// at the end:
view->clearSelection(); 
// tried view->selectionModel()->clear() and view->selectionModel()->clearSelection() too
// but got the same result
}
```

It compiles just right, but when I run and do a selection it crashes at the end with this error message:

> ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qlist.h, line 282

I tried other tricks as well:
Reimplementing showEvent method and calling clearSelection from that context, but didn't help :(

My Qt version is 4.8.1. Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also checked that view->selectionModel()->hasSelection() returns true and view->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0)->empty() returns false. I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Doesn't it produce a recursive call from `view->clearSelection()` to the `MyWidget::select()` function?

Comment: @vahancho It might be the problem, but still the error seems pretty inaccurate. However... how can I deselect rows after handling the selection then?

Comment: You were right vahancho. I just had to add a line to my select funtion. `if( selected.indexes( ).empty( ) ) return;` Thanks for locating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... it was a pretty dumb mistake. As vahancho said, it implied a recursive call. I had to add a line to my select function to skip the second ( recursive ) call.

```
if( selected.indexes( ).empty( ) ) return;
```

It was my big mistake, but maybe it helps others too.